# Scale View to Fit Superview (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, scale, vstack

I have a `CustomView` and it's frame needs to be 2000w x 2000h. I want to put this view in a `VStack` along with other `View`s. The problem is that, obviously, my `CustomView` is 2000x2000 which of course does not correctly fit on iPhones. I want this view to **scale** to fit in the VStack. I don't want this view's frame to change but to scale itself to fit in the `VStack`.

I've tried `.scaledToFit()` but I have not gotten the correct result by any means. How would I go about doing this? Please excuse any ignorance on my part, I've been learning SwiftUI over the past week or so.

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            CustomView()
                .scaledToFit()
            // ...other views
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct CustomView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            // ...content
        }
        .frame(width: 2000, height: 2000)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `to scale to fit in the VStack. I don't want this view's frame to change`. This two conditions are contrary to each other.

Comment: @burnsi I don't want the `CustomView`'s actual frame to change (it needs to stay at 2000x2000) but I want it to scale down to fit in the `VStack`. Meaning it would literally scale the `CustomView` and all of its subviews down to fit. Much like how the `.scaleEffect()` works.

Comment: This may just be a confusion about terms, but if it scales down the frame changes. If you want your view to layout in respect to relative values use `GeometryReader`. There are a lot of tuts and questions around.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have a solution, it works for me at least.

Basically, I put `CustomView` in a `GeometryReader`, which is in a `Group`. The `Group` keeps the aspect ratio of the `CustomView` (in my case 1:1). Then, in the `GeometryReader`, I'm setting the `CustomView`'s position to the middle of the `GeometryReader` and applying a `.scaleEffect()`. The scale effect is calculated by dividing the new height of the view by the `CustomView`'s height (luckily for me it's static at 2000).

This might not work for everyone, but it works for me. Hopefully it at least helps you!

```
Group {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
            CustomView()
                .position(x: geometry.frame(in: .local).midX, y: geometry.frame(in: .local).midY)
                .scaleEffect(geometry.size.height / 2000)
        }
    }
    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
```

Comment: Position fix my issue.